# Using conditions inside Sql Data provider

Tags: sql, yii2

I want to use conditions inside SQL data provider query as shown below

```
 $count         =   Yii::$app->db->createCommand('
                    SELECT COUNT(*) FROM screen_ticket_booking WHERE id!=:id
                    ', [':id' => 0])->queryScalar(); 
                    $dataProvider = new SqlDataProvider([
                    'sql' =>    'SELECT A1.booking_id As Booking_id,
                                A3.movie_name As Movie,
                                A4.theatre_name As Theatre,
                                A1.show_date As Show_date,
                                A2.start_time As Time,
                                A5.booking_date As Booking_date,
                                A1.id As Id

                                FROM 
                                screen_ticket_booking A1

                                LEFT OUTER JOIN screen_show_times A2 ON A1.show_time_id=A2.id
                                LEFT OUTER JOIN movies A3 ON A1.movie_id=A3.id
                                LEFT OUTER JOIN theatres A4 ON A1.theatre_id=A4.id
                                LEFT OUTER JOIN screen_ticket_booking_history A5 ON A1.booking_id=A5.booking_id

                                WHERE A1.id !=0 ',
                    if( $userid != '1')
                    {
                    $sql .= ' AND A4.users_backend_id = {$userid}';
                    }   
                    'totalCount' => $count,
                    ]);
```

i am getting an error " syntax error, unexpected 'if' (T_IF), expecting ']' "
. is it not possible to use a condition inside the SQL data provider?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to use conditions to build your query, you need to do it outside of *dataprovider*. Like this:

```
$sql = 'SELECT A1.booking_id As Booking_id,
    A3.movie_name As Movie,
    A4.theatre_name As Theatre,
    A1.show_date As Show_date,
    A2.start_time As Time,
    A5.booking_date As Booking_date,
    A1.id As Id

    FROM 
    screen_ticket_booking A1

    LEFT OUTER JOIN screen_show_times A2 ON A1.show_time_id=A2.id
    LEFT OUTER JOIN movies A3 ON A1.movie_id=A3.id
    LEFT OUTER JOIN theatres A4 ON A1.theatre_id=A4.id
    LEFT OUTER JOIN screen_ticket_booking_history A5 ON A1.booking_id=A5.booking_id

    WHERE A1.id !=0 '

if( $userid != '1')
{
    $sql .= ' AND A4.users_backend_id = {$userid}';
}
```

And then `$dataProvider = new SqlDataProvider([
                    'sql' => $sql,
                    'totalCount' => $count,
                    ]);`

Also consider use of [query builder](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-db-query.html) which provides more flexible and independent of DBMS way of creating *SELECT* SQL statements